# Program with functions to multiply a matrix by a scalar

Tags: c, function

This is a program I typed in (word for word, letter for letter, special character for special character) from a book Programming in C. But my compiler doesn't compile it (Xcode 4.6.3, Terminal 2.2.3).

Here is the program and below error messages I get. I don't see why I get these error messages.

```
// program to multiply two-dimensional matrix by a scalar

#include <stdio.h>

void scalar_multiply (int num_rows, int num_columns, int matrix[num_rows][num_columns], int scalar);
void display_matrix  (int num_rows, int num_columns, matrix[num_rows][num_columns]);

int main(void)
{
    int sample_matrix[3][5] =
    {
        { 7, 16, 55, 13, 12},
        {12, 10, 52,  0,  7},
        {-2,  1,  2,  4,  9}
    };

    printf("Original matrix:\n");
    display_matrix(3, 5, sample_matrix);

    scalar_multiply(3, 5, sample_matrix, 2);

    printf("\nMultiplied by 2:\n");
    display_matrix(3, 5, sample_matrix);

    scalar_multiply(3, 5, sample_matrix, -1);

    printf("\nMultiplied by -1:\n");
    display_matrix(3, 5, sample_matrix);

    return 0;
}

// function to multiply a matrix by a scalar
void scalar_multiply (int num_rows, int num_columns, int matrix[num_rows][num_columns], int scalar)
{
    int row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
        for (column = 0; column < num_columns; column++)
            matrix[row][column] *= scalar;
}

void display_matrix (int num_rows, int num_columns, matrix[num_rows][num_columns])
{
    int row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < num_columns; column++)
            printf("%5i", matrix[row][column]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Error messages:

```
prog7-14.c:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘matrix’
prog7-14.c: In function ‘main’:
prog7-14.c:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘display_matrix’
prog7-14.c:23: error: too many arguments to function ‘display_matrix’
prog7-14.c:28: error: too many arguments to function ‘display_matrix’
prog7-14.c: At top level:
prog7-14.c:42: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘matrix’
prog7-14.c: In function ‘display_matrix’:
prog7-14.c:49: error: ‘matrix’ undeclared (first use in this function)
prog7-14.c:49: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
prog7-14.c:49: error: for each function it appears in.)
Allas-MacBook-Pro:ch7 Alla$ touch prog7-14.c
Allas-MacBook-Pro:ch7 Alla$ gcc prog7-14.c -o prog7-14
prog7-14.c:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘matrix’
prog7-14.c: In function ‘main’:
prog7-14.c:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘display_matrix’
prog7-14.c:23: error: too many arguments to function ‘display_matrix’
prog7-14.c:28: error: too many arguments to function ‘display_matrix’
prog7-14.c: At top level:
prog7-14.c:42: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘matrix’
prog7-14.c: In function ‘display_matrix’:
prog7-14.c:49: error: ‘matrix’ undeclared (first use in this function)
prog7-14.c:49: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
prog7-14.c:49: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> `void display_matrix  (int num_rows, int num_columns, matrix[num_rows][num_columns]);`

must be

```
void display_matrix  (int num_rows, int num_columns, int matrix[num_rows][num_columns]);
```

You forgot `int` before `matrix[num_rows][num_columns]`

Answer (score 1):

While **declaring** the prototype and **defining** the `display_matrix` function you missed to type `int` before the `matrix[num_rows][num_columns]`.

This is producing **Error:** too many arguments to the `display_matrix`.

1. Make a change to the `display_matrix` prototype.

   ```
   void display_matrix (int num_rows, int num_columns, int matrix[num_rows][num_columns]);
   ```
2. Update the similar change to `display_matrix` definition.

   ```
   void display_matrix (int num_rows, int num_columns, int matrix[num_rows][num_columns])
   {
       int row, column;
       .... rest of the code
   }
   ```